How to view boot logs for debugging the virsh shutdown
I am using virsh start guest which starts the domain, but soon the guest goes into the shutdown state which can be confirmed using the below command:
virsh list  --all
 Id   Name          State
------------------------------
 -    guest   shut off

I tried virsh reboot guest and restart the guest, but the same issue is observed.
Often the RHEL9 based guest VM comes up in the running state. This is an intermittent issue and i am using the same domain XML file, hence there are no issues in the domain XML configurations.

Can you please suggest how to debug this issue?
How can we get the boot logs (/var/log/boot.log is also not created)?

